# Set splitter handle as QScrollArea corner widget?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qsplitter

I'm trying to display files and folders like column view in Mac finder.

[image: Mac finder image]

I was able get the basic structure with the help of ListViews and QFileSystemModel. Then I set the splitter handle as a corner widget for the scroll area. I have two issues here

- When I resize the listview, the splitter handle disappears.
- Even after setting the splitter handle width to 0, I see spacing between
  listviews.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class PopulateList(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setModel()
        self.show()

        self.ui.splitter.setHandleWidth(0)#not working
        self.ui.listView.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.ui.listView.setCornerWidget(self.getCornerWidget(self.ui.splitter))

        self.ui.closePushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.ui.listView.clicked.connect(self.showSubFiles)

    def getCornerWidget(self, splitter):
        self.handle=splitter.handle(1)
        layout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.handle)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setMargin(0)

        for i in range(0,2):
            line = QtGui.QFrame(self.handle)
            line.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.VLine)
            layout.addWidget(line)

        return self.handle

    def showSubFiles(self, index):
        root_path = self.model.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        self.model1=QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model1.setRootPath(root_path)
        self.ui.listView_1.setModel(self.model1)
        self.ui.listView_1.setRootIndex(self.model1.index(root_path))

    def setModel(self):
        root_path=os.path.expanduser("~")
        self.model=QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(root_path)
        self.model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Dirs)
        self.ui.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.ui.listView.setRootIndex(self.model.index(root_path))

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(602, 365)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(Form)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("splitter"))
        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(self.splitter)
        self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))
        self.listView_1 = QtGui.QListView(self.splitter)
        self.listView_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView_1"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.closePushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.closePushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("closePushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.closePushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(0, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.closePushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Close", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    listView=PopulateList()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to use QColumnView?  It is exactly this.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolumnview.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
view = QtWidgets.QColumnView()
view.setModel(model)
model.setRootPath("/")
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: Screenshot of QColumnView backed by QFileSystemModel]

Comment: Yes, I've been looking to create this kind of widget. Thanks. BTW I face the two issues in the program I sent. Is that a Qt issue?